# HTML CSS: Use Collapsible Toggle with SVG Icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-ui

I want to replace a FontAwesome Icon with Google Materials SVG Icon, after a collapsible table button toggle is pressed (goes from down arrow to up arrow). Current Code is this. I cannot get Google Material Icons code working. How would i fix this?

Should work like this, except with Google icons:

https://codepen.io/tofanelli/pen/waadRY

**Font Awesome**

```
.card-header .accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114"; 
    float: right; 
    color: grey; 
}


.card-header .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    content: "\e113";
}
```

**Google Material Icons:**

```
.card-header .accordion-toggle:after .material-icons{
    content: "\e5cf"; 
    float: right; 
    color: grey; 
}


etc
```

Picture example from toggling button:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to include the Google web font

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Inside the css definition for the toggle buttons you need to replace

```
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
```

by

```
font-family: 'Material Icons';
```

and lastly

```
content: "\e114";
```

by either

```
content: "expand_less";
```

or

```
content: "expand_more";
```

Here's an example based on your code:

```css
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: "expand_less";
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: "expand_more";
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">


  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- end container -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks this is very helpful, one more question, is there a .accordion-toggle. 
Uncollapsed or Not Collapsed Property?  For some reason when I start the project in my solution, the arrow is Up when Collapsed, but after clicking it twice to reset it, Arrow goes to down when collapsed, (the correct way)

Comment: You can do this by manually appending **collapsed** to the closed `<a>` elements class. I modified my example above.